# Power Query Duration format consistency

Tags: powerquery, time-format

i'm using Power Query in Excel to filter some .txt files, extract a time value from each and show the results.
The problem is the original data which comes in 3 different formats:

```
3:42.807
0:01:48.19
3:46
```

how can i convert them in a consistent format (e.g. 3:42.80).
I need to show minutes, seconds and eventually milliseconds.

I tried several different `Duration.ToText` or `Duration.From` but i had more problems.
Also i'd like to avoid adding an extra column just to calculate the duration format. Is it possible to convert the original column only?

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Time", type duration}})
```

This is the formula from Power query i sued to convert to duration, but i don't like this format "d.hh.mm.ss" etc. it gives me errors. It would be perfect if it was a Duration type but only displaying minutes, seconds and milliseconds (3:41.23)

Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the displayed format for a given column type in the query editor. If you need a different format, then you'll have to convert it into a text column.

Here's how I tinkered with it:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMrYyMdKzMDBXitWJVjKwMjC0MrHQM7QEc4FyZkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Time = _t]),
    StandardizeFormat = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Time", each Duration.ToText(Duration.FromText(if List.Count(Text.Split(_, ":")) = 2 then "0:" & _ else _)), type text}}),
    TrimZeros = Table.TransformColumns(StandardizeFormat, {{"Time", each Text.TrimEnd(Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "00:0"),"0"), type text}})
in
    TrimZeros
```

The `if List.Count(Text.Split(_, ":")) = 2 then "0:" & _ else _` part tells it to prepend `0:` to the beginning if there aren't already two colons (so that the conversion do duration doesn't break).

Comment: thanks for the answer Alexis. i forgot to mention that the 3 time formats are present in 3 different excel files. so each file has only 1 type of format (like in the picture). Also how can i implement it my formula to not lose all the previous steps i made (filter rows, split text etc)?

Comment: You can add those steps after all the previous steps. Just reference whatever the previous step is instead of `Source`.

Comment: i did it. i just have an issue when the "0:00" format has 2 digits for the minutes (e.g. 14:24.98). the TrimZero trims all the line giving a blank cell

Comment: `= Table.TransformColumns(StandardizeFormat, {{"Column1", each Text.TrimEnd(Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "00:0"),"0"), type text}})`

Comment: You could use `"00:"` instead and that would pad single-digit minutes with a zero.

Comment: it worked like that `= Table.TransformColumns(StandardizeFormat, {{"Column1", each Text.TrimEnd(Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "00:"),"0"), type text}})`

Comment: one last thing, how to cut the last digit of millisecs? `03:41.876`

Comment: Given that the text is padded to a consistent shape, you could use Transform > Extract > First Characters in the GUI, which should produce M code like `each Text.First(_, 8)` for the transformation function.

Comment: I meant. `Text.Start`. The one I mentioned doesn't exist.

Comment: i think i will leave the milliseconds like that, thanks for the help man :)